# Why am I getting no output?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a pretty simple question really - why am I getting no output? This is the site: https://riven.market/list/PC/Veiled. I thought the problem was the spaces in class name but turns out its natural and shouldnt cause any problems. If you have any questions let me know in the comments

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://riven.market/list/PC/Veiled")

c = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
all = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"riven-list" })
for item in all:
    print("Name" + item.find("div", {"class": "attribute weapon"}).text.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", ""))
```

Comment: There is no `<div>` tag with class `riven-list`

Comment: That page doesn't have such a div. Don't use the inspector for scraping projects as it will mislead you. Use "View Source" only.

Comment: Somehow it still doesnt work

Comment: @Stasiek It is not working because if you view the page source, there are no `<div>` tags with `riven-list`. like what Selcuk said, dont use the inspector object to get the element's ID, instead view the page source to grab it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my workaround way, which is to find the actual URL the query is sending the request to. You can find it by `rightclick`-> `inspect element` -> `network` -> `Find the get request`

[image]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# instead of sending to this
main = requests.get("https://riven.market/list/PC/Veiled")

ajax_url = "https://riven.market/_modules/riven/showrivens.php?baseurl=Lw==&platform=PC&limit=25&recency=-1&veiled=true&onlinefirst=true&polarity=all&rank=all&mastery=16&weapon=Any&stats=Any&neg=all&price=99999&rerolls=-1&sort=time&direction=ASC&page=1&time=1565851905857"
re = requests.get(ajax_url)
c = re.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
all_divs = soup.find_all("div", class_ ="attribute weapon" )
for item in all_divs:
        print(item.text)
```

Outputs

```
        Pistol Riven Mod
        new

        Pistol Riven Mod
        > 1 day

        Pistol Riven Mod
        > 1 day

        Pistol Riven Mod
        new

        Pistol Riven Mod
        new

        Pistol Riven Mod
        > 1 day

        Pistol Riven Mod
        > 1 day

        Pistol Riven Mod
        > 1 day

        Melee Riven Mod
        > 1 day

        Shotgun Riven Mod
        > 1 day

        Pistol Riven Mod
        > 1 day

        Pistol Riven Mod
        > 1 day

        Pistol Riven Mod
        > 1 week

        Melee Riven Mod
        > 1 week

        Rifle Riven Mod
        > 1 week

        Shotgun Riven Mod
        > 1 week

        Pistol Riven Mod
        > 1 week

        Pistol Riven Mod
        > 1 week

        Pistol Riven Mod
        > 1 week

        Pistol Riven Mod
        > 1 week

        Rifle Riven Mod
        > 1 week

        Rifle Riven Mod
        > 1 week

        Melee Riven Mod
        > 1 week

        Shotgun Riven Mod
        > 1 week

        Rifle Riven Mod
        > 1 week
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you want exactly as your output, but you need to make a few modifications to the request url and add the query parameters:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://riven.market/_modules/riven/showrivens.php'

payload = {
'baseurl': 'Lw==',
'platform': 'PC',
'limit': '25',
'recency': '-1',
'veiled': 'true',
'onlinefirst': 'true',
'polarity': 'all',
'rank': 'all',
'mastery': '16',
'weapon': 'Any',
'stats': 'Any',
'neg': 'all',
'price': '99999',
'rerolls': '-1',
'sort': 'time',
'direction': 'ASC',
'page': '1',
'time': '1565851478713'}

r = requests.get(url, params=payload)

c = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
all_divs = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"riven " })
for item in all_divs:
    print("Name" + item.find("div", {"class": "attribute weapon"}).text.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", ""))
```

**Output:**

```
newtolRivenMod
>1daylRivenMod
>1daylRivenMod
newtolRivenMod
newtolRivenMod
>1daylRivenMod
>1daylRivenMod
>1daylRivenMod
>1dayRivenMod
>1dayunRivenMod
>1daylRivenMod
>1daylRivenMod
>1weekRivenMod
>1weekivenMod
>1weekivenMod
>1weeknRivenMod
>1weekRivenMod
>1weekRivenMod
>1weekRivenMod
>1weekRivenMod
>1weekivenMod
>1weekivenMod
>1weekivenMod
>1weeknRivenMod
>1weekivenMod
```